# SwiftUI Lifecycle on macOS: present new scene with its own viewmodel

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have a macOS app which I'd like to open several instances of in separate windows. For demonstration purposes, I have this tiny example project here:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MultipleWindowsApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MyView()
                .environmentObject(ViewModel())
                .frame(minWidth: 200, minHeight: 200)
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $vm.toggleState, label: {
            Text("Some Toggle")
        })
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var toggleState = false
}
```

As it is, a new window created from the menu bar will have a reference to the same ViewModel instance (toggling in one window toggles the other and vice versa).
I failed to find a simple answer on how I can have different windows with their own respective viewmodels (please note: I am not handling documents here that need to get saved etc., I am just consuming and visualising an api in my app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snapshot of Apple API documentation

```
/// Every window created from the group maintains independent state. For
/// example, for each new window created from the group the system allocates new
/// storage for any ``State`` or ``StateObject`` variables instantiated by the
/// scene's view hierarchy.
///
/// You typically use a window group for the main interface of an app that isn't
/// document-based. For document-based apps, use a ``DocumentGroup`` instead.
@available(iOS 14.0, macOS 11.0, tvOS 14.0, watchOS 7.0, *)
public struct WindowGroup<Content> : Scene where Content : View {
```

so, try the following (cannot test now):

```
@main
struct MultipleWindowsApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MyView()
                .frame(minWidth: 200, minHeight: 200)
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()      // << this one !!
    
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $vm.toggleState, label: {
            Text("Some Toggle")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly, what I was missing, thanks. So I guess  if in my real application I want to use the viewmodel instance as an EnvironmentObject, I just inject it one level lower (in this example in MyView). Very helpful, as always!

Comment: I got to this solution as well. The issue is you can’t use commands for your app in macOS when you want to use the model.